# how can I create an automated index html/php file of a folder/file(pdfs) structure (a basic document structure/store

Tags: indexing, document, sitemap

I need to make part of my site a basic pdf document store with one index page to access any of the pdfs i upload. is there a way to automatically update the index...ie the index is listing the folder/tree structure/sitemap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ways to do this, provided that you are in a Apache/PHP enviroment:

[Apache DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) and perhaps Use [h5ai](http://larsjung.de/h5ai/) to create fancy indexs.

Use PHP [`glob`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function to read the filesystem and display links to them.